# String won't convert to int ready for query

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to convert a field from a string to an int, then pass it to a query using tableadapters.

I have the following function:

```
protected String countResponses(String value)
{
    String input = value.ToString();
    int fordb = Int32.Parse(input);

    FrontendTableAdapters.ForumTableAdapter ta = new FrontendTableAdapters.ForumTableAdapter();
    DataTable table = ta.CountPosts(value);

    if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        return table.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
    return "Unknown";
    }
}
```

It is working greate up to putting it in CountPosts() where I get the following error:

Error   4
Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Data.DataTable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\WebApps\Figmentville\Figmentville\yoursay\Default.aspx.cs 49  31

I think this is because it is looking for an int.  But haven't I already converted it to an int?

Thanks

Dave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we don't know what `ForumTableAdapter` is, it isn't clear what `CountPosts` returns, but if this is actually returning a `DataTable` (but typed as `object`) it *sounds* like you just want:

```
 DataTable table = (DataTable)ta.CountPosts(value);
```

but then, I also expect `Count...` to return an `int`...

---

Also; minor point: the line `String input = value.ToString();` is both unnecessary and potentially a cause of a `null` bug (but not in this case) - you should be able to just use:

```
int fordb = int.Parse(value);
```

(and remove the `input` variable completely)

Comment: Hello.  Thanks for you response. The query is a select count.  The query definitely works.  If I put (DataTable) infront like you have the site loads without errors but when trying to pass anything to it i get an error - 

Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Data.DataTable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1):

you are passing in `value` which is the string parameter, you have parsed it into the variable `fordb`, thats the int you should pass in

edit

also, why do you `ToString` `value` when that pararameter is already a string (when you pass the output into the variable `input`)